# Beginning development on Mac OS using Qt

Tags: c++, macos, qt

It would be of great help ,if some one can give me some links or some books which i can read to start developing Qt application on MAC OS using Xcode(C++).I have some experience on developing Qt applications on Windows but none on MAC.I also went through Qt documentation to understand how to integrate Qt on a MAC system but that was not enough,since i am entirely new to MAC.
So i request you all to guide me where to start learning about MAC OS and Qt.
Also what are the pre-requisites which i should be aware of to start development on MAC

Comment: The Qt API is the same for all systems that have Qt. That's kind of the point with a platform independent API.

Comment: May be i question is not clear enough,i understand that Qt classes are platform independent ,my question was more towards what i should know while writing a application on MAC OS .For example packaging my application in a bundle and things like that

Comment: One thing to be aware of is macdeployqt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, have you installed Qt successfully?

- [Installation instructions for Qt on Mac](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/install-mac.html)

Next, you will want to configure Xcode

- [SO walkthrough for setting up up a new Xcode C++ project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282081/how-do-i-set-up-a-c-project-in-xcode-4)
- [SO question with some great answers about setting up Qt with Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18500314/how-to-set-up-xcode-to-work-with-instead-of-qt-creator)

Start with a basic tutorial, to check that everything works

- [Qt tutorial](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/gettingstartedqt.html)

If you run into windowing problems, you may need to get hold of an X window manager like [XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/). I'm guessing that you're already familiar with that sort of thing given your Windows background.

As far as *using* Qt, it should be the same on Mac as it is on Windows. As @JoachimPileborg points out, that is the point of a platform independent API!

Do be careful if you have any Os-specific dependencies. You haven't mentioned what other libraries etc you're using in the project, so I can't predict other issues that you might encounter.

Any more specific problems, or is that enough to get you started?

Comment: Thanks for the help and your feedback the links which you gave are a good start